# Where is the name "coset" in group theory from?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, math-history

One of the most important application of "[coset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset)", I think, is to prove the [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29), which was not originally stated in the group theoretic terms. In some textbooks I  have read about abstract algebra, I didn't find any history about "coset".

Here are my **questions**:

> Where is the concept "coset" from? And what was it originally used for?

Comment: .. and what are they called in other languages ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **Mathword** http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html for first use of this.

Comment: ...where it says "COSET was used in 1910 by G. A. Miller in Quarterly Journal of Mathematics."

Comment: The first use doesn't directly tell us where the name comes from in the sense of etymology, which is what I think was the request.  My *guess* is that coset might be a contraction of "complementary set", but I have no real evidence for that.

Comment: G. A. Miller is a hero of mine. It is nice that the word traces back to him :)

Answer (score 19):

The answer is relatively simple. It does appear that G.A. Miller did indeed originate the use of the term in his early publications on group theory. It literally means: "co-set". The prefix co- is from the Latin "com-" meaning (among other things) "together with" (as an example, the Spanish derivative "con" simply means "with"). A "co-set" of a subgroup H of a group G, is a subset of G "occuring with" H, and sharing the most important property of H *as a set*, which is its cardinality. It is perfectly natural to think of the cosets gH of a subgroup H as "sister sets" of the subgroup H, each one formed by multiplying H by some element g of the parent group G. This meaning of co- is the same one we use in such words as co-pilot, or co-worker.

I think it doubtful that "co-" was intended as an abbreviation for "complementary" or "common", as the modern penchant for abbreviation was not so common at the start of the 20th century.

In any case, in *Theory and Applications of Finite Groups* (1916), Miller indicates that he originated the term, the previous one being *Nebengruppen*, which I believe translates roughly as "subgroup". Perhaps a better term might have been "translate" of H, a term used in the study of topological groups (esp. Lie groups). It appears that the original use of the word "co-set" was its current use.

The utility of the concept of cosets extends far beyond Lagrange's Theorem. For (a rather simple) example, in the integers, the coset $1+2\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all odd integers, which is often very useful as being considered as "a single entity".

Comment: Perhaps somebody who is native German speaker will give a better explanation, but I think that a reasonable translation of *Nebengruppe* could be something like close group, neighborhood group, since the preposition [neben](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neben) means near, next to.  
Based on this [article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebenklasse_%28Mathematik%29) from German Wikipedia, it seems that the term *Nebenklassen* is used today.

Comment: In Dutch one uses the same term: _nevenklasse_. Perhaps one coudl translate it as _neighboring class/group_ or _adjacent class/group_. Personally I prefer left/right translate instead of left/right coset, especially for topological groups, I find this term more descriptive: $gH$ is what you get when you translate $H$ via $g$.

Comment: @wildildildlife: the term for coset in Russian is also "adjacent class".

Answer (score 4):

Gallian's "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" says that Galois invented the concept of a coset in 1830, but the name coset was not used until 1910 by G.A. Miller.

Comment: Did Galois use a word to refer to cosets?